# why we should not use synchronized with run method?

Tags: java, multithreading

Everytime I get different output when I run this program.
Is there any way to get consistent output with in run method only?

```
public class MultiBasic1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChildThread th1=new ChildThread();
        ChildThread th2= new ChildThread();
        ChildThread th3= new ChildThread();
        ChildThread th4= new ChildThread();
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
        th3.start();
        th4.start();
    }
}

class ChildThread extends Thread{

    synchronized public void run(){
        for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Is there any chance to get consistent output with in run method only"* - Don't use threads, call `run` directly

Comment: @MadProgrammer if i call run directly then i will not get benefit of multi threading

Comment: If you want only one thread to be able to `run` at a time, you're not going to get any benefit out of multithreading either.

Comment: @VikasMandeliya What benefit are you going to get by blocking the other threads until one has finished?

Comment: @MadProgrammer to get benefit of synchronization

Comment: @VikasMandeliya To what point?  You'd get the same result just calling `run` directly

Comment: @user2357112 then what is the use of synchronization in java ??

Comment: synchronization is to protect access to data shared between threads.

Comment: `sychronization` only means that only one thread may enter the protected block of code, it does not control the order in which the gain access.  In your example, each thread is been allowed to enter the `sychronization` block simultaneously (or near enough) because you have multiple instances of the class, rather than a single instance been accessed by multiple threads

Comment: What you are asking here is completely useless, if you require that one thing be executed before another you can't use multithreading for that. It may be possible that you can refactor code such that multithreading would work fine but if you want to guarantee the order at which execution occurs in separate threads you are going about this all wrong.

Comment: @MadProgrammer...  it's sounds good this is where i was confused ..

Comment: @MattWolfe  yes correct i got the answer

Comment: Synchronizing the run method is pointless. For synchronization to make sense it has to protect data shared acrosd threads; there is no sharing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're creating a new instance of `ChildThread`, each thread is allowed to access the `run` method without restriction, as there is only one thread actually accessing the method.

To demonstrate how `synchronized` works, you'd need to have some kind shared resource, such as a `Object` which each thread could interact with

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Action action = new Action();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runner(action), "1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runner(action), "2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runner(action), "3");
        Thread t4 = new Thread(new Runner(action), "4");
        Thread t5 = new Thread(new Runner(action), "5");


        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
        t5.start();
    }

    public static class Runner implements Runnable {
        private Action action;

        public Runner(Action action) {
            this.action = action;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            action.makeItSo();
        }

    }

    public static class Action {
        public synchronized void makeItSo() {
            for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - " + index);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The above example demonstrates that only one thread can run within the `makeItSo` method, but also, that there is no guarantee over which thread will be allowed to run (ie the order)

Answer (score 1):

Why you are getting different output?

Answer:
synchronized requires an object on which lock is attained before entering the synchronized block or method.

In this case lock is being attained on the objects on which the method is executed hence thread 1 is locking on object th1, thread 2 is locking on th2 and so on.

therefore, all the threads are locking onto different objects and are allowed to run simultaneously.

How to get consistent output?

Answer

option 1: you can use join to join the threads to main thread
public class MultiBasic1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ChildThread th1=new ChildThread();
    ChildThread th2= new ChildThread();
    ChildThread th3= new ChildThread();
    ChildThread th4= new ChildThread();

    th1.setName("A");
    th2.setName("B");
    th3.setName("C");
    th4.setName("D");

    th1.start();
    th1.join();
    th2.start();
    th2.join();
    th3.start();
    th3.join();
    th4.start();
    th4.join();
}
```

}

class ChildThread extends Thread{

```
public void run(){
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
        System.out.println(i + " " + getName());
}
```

}

option 2: provide shared object for synchronized block to synchronize the threads

public class MultiBasic1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ChildThread th1=new ChildThread();
    ChildThread th2= new ChildThread();
    ChildThread th3= new ChildThread();
    ChildThread th4= new ChildThread();

    th1.setName("A");
    th2.setName("B");
    th3.setName("C");
    th4.setName("D");

    th1.start();
    th2.start();
    th3.start();
    th4.start();
}
```

}

class ChildThread extends Thread{

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();
public void run(){

    synchronized (lock) {
        for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
            System.out.println(i + " " + getName());
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here there is even no need of synchronization since you are using different objects for calling the run method.

Synchronization works when multiples threads of one object is in picture.

Above example will be more meaningful if you do something like below.

```
public class MultiBasic1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChildThread th1=new ChildThread();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(th1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(th1);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(th1);
        Thread t4 = new Thread(th1);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
    }
}

class ChildThread extends Thread{

    synchronized public void run(){
        for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```